# How do I get the solarized colour scheme working with gnome-terminal, tmux and vim?

Tags: vim, colors, tmux, gnome-terminal

There's a lot of questions around this, but it's because there are so many variables. I had to piece together instructions from many sites before I got this working.

First, I could not easily set up the 16 solarized colour definitions in gnome-terminal (I did it by hand/clicking only to realise that I'd not got the order/mapping correct). Once I fixed that I moved on...

Then I had solarized colours working in vim OK-ish, but there was some odd black backgrounds appearing in certain highlighting. Once I fixed that, I moved on...

Then I realised vim went v. wonky once running inside tmux. This is massively debated, but very few of the answers (which mostly say about setting `TERM` to `xterm-256colors`) worked for me. I eventually fixed that too.

[Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) is a very nice palette (although I darkened the darkest base colour and lightened the lightest as I prefer the higher contrast and found tmux's 'white' far far too yellow on my calibrated screen - prob fine on a typical uncalibrated laptop screen as they're usually way too blue!), so I'm posting this question with its answer to share the results of my learning.

Comment: I use xterm-256color (not GNOME terminal), tmux, and vim and don't remember having to jump through anywhere near this many hoops.  The only thing I had to do was solarize the terminal (xterm uses XResources instead of profiles) which was a slight pain to figure out, add  `solarized.vim` and I was all set.

Comment: Helped me: http://michaelheap.com/solarized-with-iterm2/, http://michaelheap.com/getting-solarized-working-on-ubuntu/, http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solarized gives very specific colours. You **can't really achieve these colours in a standard 256 colour palette**. The only way you can achieve this is through setting up the exact colours in your terminal emulator, then apps think they're just using standard 16 colours (8 + 8 brights) but these have been accurately mapped to the Solarized palette.

Gnome terminal does not provide a very easy way to export/import palettes or profiles, but you can do it with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DARK_BG='#000014141A1A'
# original: DARK_BG='#00002B2B3636'
LIGHTEST='#FFFFFBFBF0F0'
# original: LIGHTEST='#FDFDF6F6E3E3'

gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_background" --type bool false
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_colors" --type bool false
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/palette" --type string "#070736364242:#D3D301010202:#858599990000:#B5B589890000:#26268B8BD2D2:#D3D336368282:#2A2AA1A19898:#EEEEE8E8D5D5:$DARK_BG:#CBCB4B4B1616:#58586E6E7575:#65657B7B8383:#838394949696:#6C6C7171C4C4:#9393A1A1A1A1:$LIGHTEST"
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color" --type string "$DARK_BG"
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color" --type string "#65657B7B8383"
```

Nb. here I've overridden Solarized's darkest and lightest colours. You can use the originals if you like, as commented.

Good enough. Now install the [Solarized vim colours file](https://raw.github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/master/colors/solarized.vim) by placing that file in `~.vim/colors/solarized.vim`.

Now you can tell Vim to use that colour scheme with `colo solarized`. But this did not quite work and I had to tell Vim to use a 16 colour pallete, `set t_Co=16`. I stuck both of those in my `~/.vimrc` file.

Now vim colours were working, but not if it ran inside tmux.

This next bit is very confusing. Most advice says about setting `TERM` outside tmux to `xterm-256colors`, but when I did that tmux would not even start. It confused me, too: doesn't solarized say that the 256 colour palette is a poor approximation? Well, it is confusing, and anyway, it wasn't working so I needed another way forward:

Create a file `/tmp/foo` containing:

```
xterm-16color|xterm with 16 colors,
    colors#16, use=xterm,
```

Then install this with `sudo tic /tmp/foo`

Finally, alias `tmux` as follows:

```
alias tmux='TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-16color TERM=xterm-16color tmux -2'
```

I now get **exactly** the right colours in the terminal, in vim, and in vim-inside-tmux. Nb. the `-2` option tells `tmux` to use a 256 colour palette, which is really confusing because the env variables would appear to be telling it otherwise... I genuinely don't know, and I'm afraid I don't really care to climb that learning curve because I now have a beautiful coloured terminal that Just Works.

Comment: `set t_Co=16` did the trick for me. Before setting that option syntax hightlighting did not work at all.

Comment: It's amusing how much work you need to do to get 16 colours working in a text editor!

Comment: Note: I'm finding that in Gnome Terminal 3.18.3 (in Ubuntu 16.04) this no longer works - doesn't seem to accept the colours and using vim's t_Co=256 gives better results.

Answer (score 9):

I also found this project:

https://github.com/sigurdga/gnome-terminal-colors-solarized

Thanks for the tips :-)

Comment: Yes yes and yes! Use this script, don't bother with all the hacking in the accepted answer. This "just works".

Comment: Wonderful! This is so much better. Thank you.

Comment: On some installs it works. On some it's too blue.